# No java program works after adding a jar to classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, lua

Am trying to write a Java program that calls a Lua script which works with Redis.
So I need the luajava jar file.
When I tried doing this in Eclipse IDE, it didnt work. So i decided to use an editor and terminal in ubuntu to do the same.

Now after I add this jar to the classpath, using 
export CLASSPATH=/path/luajava_1.1.jar
command, not even simple programs that need this jar is working.

In the screenshot that i've attached, you can see that Test.java is a simple java program which runs fine before adding the jar. But after adding jar to classpath, it gives an error "could not find or load main class Test"

I need help in fixing this. Also any guidance regarding how to go about executing lua script in java will be appreciated. I read about LuaEclipse which seems like a plugin to eclipse to execute lua scripts. Should I install that? or is there any other option?

Comment: Most likely you need to `export CLASSPATH=.:/path/luajava_1.1.jar` so that you can still `java Test` with a `Test.class` in your working directory.

Comment: I see no screenshots. Are you sure you're supposed to be modifying the system classpath? Usually you work on your Java Project's *Java Build Path*.

Comment: What about the previous classpath value?  You've just wiped it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical form for adding something to the current CLASSPATH is the same as you do with PATH and similar:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/luajava_1.1.jar
```

For running a program with a main class in a .class file in or below your working directory make sure that CLASSPATH contains the working directory. To add:

```
export CLASSPATH=".:$CLASSPATH"
```

If Eclipse doesn't find that jar, it has to be added via Project -> Properties -> [Java Build Path] -> Libraries.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was tryin CLASSPATH=/path/luajava_1.1.jar which was replacing the classpath with luajava.jar file. CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/luajava_1.1.jar appends luajava.jar to the classpath.  :)